# Sum function satisfies the differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

I can't seem to prove this and got another equation. It would be appreciated if someone could help with this thank you!

Question :Show that the sum function

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^ ∞   \frac{(-1)^n{x^{2n}}}{(4^n)(n!)^2}$$

satisfies the differential equation:

$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+x^2f(x)=0 $$

for all $x∈ℝ$

My attempt:

I did the $f'(x)$ and the $f''(x)$  and inserted in the equation and it doesn't equal to $0$. For me it satisfies $x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)-4n^2f(x)$ instead of $x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+x^2f(x)$. My $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^ ∞  \frac{(-1)^n(2n){x^{2n-1}}}{(4^n)(n!)^2}$ and my $f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^ ∞  \frac{(-1)^n(2n)(2n-1){x^{2n-2}}}{(4^n)(n!)^2}$

Comment: $x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)-4n^2f(x)$ for which $n$? – You should show what you computed for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$, so that we can point out the error.

Comment: I think you mean $\sum_{n=0}^ ∞   \frac{\color{red}(-1\color{red})^n{x^{2n}}}{4^n\cdot (n!)^2}$

Comment: An expression like $$\sum_{n=0}^ ∞  = \frac{(-1)^n{x^{2n}}}{(4^n)(n!)^2}$$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry i have added and fixed my equations

Comment: You want to combine these sums into a single summation over $n$. At first glance I would also suggest turning this into a telescoping series, as that should be possible with the sum of shifted alternating series